# twitter-bootstrap js to toggle all collapse for all elements of a common class

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bunch of elements (code-blocks) I'd like to be able to collapse using twitter-bootstrap's javascript, such as

```
some text

<div class="highlight">
code code
</div>

some more text text 

<div class="highlight">
code code
</div>
```

I can add the following javascript to make all of these elements collapse:

```
$('highlight').collapse({
  toggle: true
})
```

Now I'd like to add a button to toggle the collapse/show for these elements.  Any ideas?

### Solution requirements

I'm looking for a solution that

1. extends but doesn't have to change the original html with the code blocks.  For instance, I cannot add ids to the 'highlight' divs or more divs around the code blocks.
2. In a similar goal, I'd like it to apply to all highlight class divs.

Note that using the normal collapse class from twitter bootstrap, such as:

```
<a href="#block1" data-toggle="collapse">toggle</a>
<div class="collapse" id="#block1">
code code
</div>
```

doesn't gneralize in this way, since it needs ids, and if they are repeated, it only toggles the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

twitter bootstrap uses jQuery behind the scenes so you should just be able to add a button, then add a click event to collapse the code blocks.

```
<input type="button" value="show/hide" id="toggle_code" />
$(function(){
    $('#toggle_code').click(function(){
        $('.highlight').collapse({
          toggle: true
        })
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I must have missed something (sorry I'm new to javascript).  Here's [my attempt to use this](http://carlboettiger.info/collapse.html).  Thanks again!

Comment: ..edit. never mind, just wrap the function in a $(function(){  //code here }) //wait until dom is ready

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow what that.  How do I get a toggle button out of just wrapping my code in another function?  your original solution sounds good, I'm not sure why it's not working for me.

Comment: @cboettig I've updated the code block with the document ready wrapper. You're also going to need to move the jquery script tag to your header, <script src="assets/js/jquery.js.pagespeed.jm.F1sj5uxJzN.js"></script> should be at the top of your page, just so that the Jquery Object is defined when we do our selector

Comment: Okay, just tried the new function and moving the javascript loading to the header, still no go ([same link](http://carlboettiger.info/collapse.html))...  So the function definition doesn't need to be in a javascript tag?

Comment: wrapped the function in script tags, still nothing... tried adding the definition of the function in the head tag right below the javascript, but that didn't work either..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12179/discussion-between-cboettig-and-jason-kulatunga)

Comment: k I've posted the answer in chat, and tested it myself on your page using firebug.